# Convert Base64 to normal PNG for copy/pasting

Tags: outlook, png, base64, highcharts, paste

I've got an HTML email template that's using a kludgy process as follows:

1. Pull data from MySQL and put it into a HighCharts chart
2. Convert the HighCharts SVG to canvas using canvg
3. Render the canvas as a Base64 PNG using canvas.toDataURL

All's well and good, the image shows up fine (except for some quirkiness in Internet Explorer), but here's the rub:

I'd like users to be able to copy and paste the entire web page into Outlook and send it out as an email. However, Outlook (and a few other clients I've tried) won't receive Base64 PNGs via copy paste -- there's a blank space where the image should be.

Does anyone know of a way to convert the Base64 into a normal PNG such that it can survive the copy/paste? Maybe this requires saving the PNG to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about this since your last question and I've come up with 3 options:

**One**

1. Stick with what you have.
2. Take the base64 string from the toDataURL, submit it back to the server via AJAX, on the backend convert it to a PNG, store it on server and serve PNG back to the page.

**Two**

1. Render highcharts SVG on the users browser.
2. Submit that SVG string to your backend server via AJAX call.
3. **On the backend**, generate a post request ([something like described here see Using PHP for POST Request](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/post_requests.html)) to the highcharts exporting server at http://export.highcharts.com/.  From looking at the highcharts [source](http://highcharts.com/js/testing-exporting.js) the request needs to contain the following posted variables:

   > filename: png filename
   >    type: from the plotOptions, the type, line,  bar,etc..
   >    width: the width in pixels of the desired png
   >    svg: the svg string
4. Get the resulting PNG, save it to your server, serve it normally.

**Three**

Switch to using the [Java Highcharts API](https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export/blob/master/README.md).  You'd have to get this running on your server.  Once you did, though, you could generate your charts entirely on the backend and just serve up the PNG file.