# Base64 html images not copying & pasting

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, base64

In reference to the advice here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429959/1582712, I am finding that images which are self contained in the HTML as binaries are not copying and pasting out of the web browser.

`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxx...">`

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/esend7881/mkhbufsp/

```html
<u><b>Route 0, C0, Start Wpt: 1, IAF Wpt: 47, Edw Rwy22L (500ft)</b></u>
<br />
<br />
<ol>Route Summary: All cases are OK with No Wind. Maximum wind tolerances for route are [120, 120, 120, 120] (excluding cases on approach after the IAF waypoint)</ol>
<ol>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
</ol>
<br />
<ol>
```

Notice that when you try copying and pasting that out of your web-browser, say into Outlook or MS Word, the images doesn't come with it.

How do I ensure binary based images come with a copy and paste?

Note: My HTML files are self contained and there is no backend server. So an AJAX type trick wouldn't work here (in reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046266/1582712)

Answer (score 0):

You can right click in chrome and choose "copy image" and you will grab the actual image.

Comment: I'm limited to Internet Explorer, and select all/copy is really the only way to make this work right

Comment: In IE 11 you can right click -> save picture as and it will save it as a png for you. It doesn't look like it will copy it straight to the clipboard, but perhaps the 'save as' will still work?